# FTP client support multi threads transfer

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, multi-threaded

OS: Windows XP SP3

Is there any FTP client that support transfer files with multi-threads? By which I mean, multiple threads for single file, and also keep a thread for browsing FTP sites.

Comment: Do you mean threaded for single file?

Comment: I think he means multiple simultaneous data streams for one file.

Comment: @Fake Name - yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Does anyone can recommend some?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your operating system.

Comment: Why would someone down vote the question? Is it because it was not very clear? This can be fixed anytime ... +1 for the question from me

Comment: Is sending multiple threads for a single file possible?

Comment: Afain, CuteFTP does, but it's not freeware.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac OS X I would suggest [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) or [Speed Download](http://www.yazsoft.com/products/speed-download/). Speed Download (despite the name) does actually have a built in FTP client.

[image: Imprint]

Comment: OP's looking for Windows. But Transmit is, in my opinion, the best on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about the FTP protocol, a threaded transfer of a single file is not possible. The transfer must start at the beginning of the file.

Some have gotten around this by taking the single file and zipping/raring it in a multipart file (multiple files that can be used to extract the large, original file)

Comment: "The transfer must start at the beginning of the file." Not 100% true. Most FTP servers support a resume (in case the connection drops). Not sure if that invalides the answer.